# SQL: Get information from multiple tables in one request

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a SQL beginner and I have a question on combining tables in a request.

I got these three tables:

Table 1: songs

Columns: id, title

Table 2: song_artists

Columns: id, song_id, artist_id

Table 3: artists

Columns: id, name

As an example, when inserting the song Memories from David Guetta feat. Kid Cudi into the database, it could look like this:

Table 1:

```
id=1, title="Memories"
```

Table 2:

```
id=1, song_id=1, artist_id=1
id=2, song_id=1, artist_id=2
```

Table 3:

```
id=1, name="David Guetta"
id=2, name="Kid Cudi"
```

Now I want to get a list of all songs with their title and their artists, but I don't know how to combine these 3 tables in one sql statement.

Comment: read about joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve data across the tables you have to use the `JOIN` which can be expressed as follows:

```
SELECT title, name 
FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE table1.id = table2.song_id AND table3.id = table2.artist_id
ORDER BY title
```

Alternatively you could use the `INNER JOIN`, which is basically the same. If so, if i'm not wrong, it would be like this:

```
SELECT table1.title, table1.name 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.song_id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.artist_id
ORDER BY table1.title
```

Comment: How does an answer with commas in the `FROM` clause get any upvotes?

Comment: What do you mean? In the join you have to separate the tables usig the comma... It is in the inner join that you don't have to... I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

Use [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp), which is a way of combining rows based on their equivalence relationship:

```
SELECT title, song_id, artist_id, name FROM Table_1, Table_2, Table_3
    INNER JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.id=Table_2.id
    INNER JOIN Table_3 ON Table_2.id=Table_3.id
```